# Hightchart - Series refers to many xAxis

Tags: highcharts

We are using spline graph : https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.xAxis

In our code we have 2 xAxis:

```
    xAxis: [
      {
        categories: formattedValues,
      },
      {
        categories: axisFiltered,
      },
    ],
```

My series :

```
    series: [
      {
        name: `Satisfaction`,
        data: formattedValues,
      },
      {
        name: `Bottom`,
        data: formattedBottomValues,
      },
      {
        name: `Top`,
        data: formattedTopValues,

      },
      {
        name: `$Average`,
        data: formattedAverageValues,
      },
    ],
```

Into our series i want to refer to the 2 xAxis and not only one. In documentation it says we can refer to only one xAxis by series :
[image]

For example in my series i would like to do that :

```
    series: [
      {
        name: `Satisfaction`,
        data: formattedValues,
        xAxis: [0, 1]
      },
      {
        name: `Bottom`,
        data: formattedBottomValues,
        xAxis: [0, 1]
      },
      {
        name: `Top`,
        data: formattedTopValues,
       xAxis: [0, 1]
      },
      {
        name: `$Average`,
        data: formattedAverageValues,
        xAxis: [0, 1]
      },
    ],
```

But the problem is currently we are allow only to do this :

```
    series: [
      {
        name: `Satisfaction`,
        data: formattedValues,
        xAxis: 1
      },
      {
        name: `Bottom`,
        data: formattedBottomValues,
        xAxis: 0
      },
      {
        name: `Top`,
        data: formattedTopValues,
       xAxis: 1
      },
      {
        name: `$Average`,
        data: formattedAverageValues,
        xAxis: 0
      },
    ],
```

The problem with that is, when i click on the legend to hide a serie, it will hide the xAxis associated. But me i don't want this xAxis to be hide because it's usefull for other series.

Answer (score 0):

Settings that give the possibility to adjust xAxis are [xAxis.min](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min) and [xAxis.max](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max) then they will stick to the second axis and the extremes will not change depending on the series.

```
  xAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data'
    },
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Histogram'
    },
    alignTicks: false,
    opposite: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 11
  }],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hymjs0wL/